# ExtJS 6 Reset chart zoom programatically

Tags: extjs, extjs6

How I can reset zoom (display the whole graph) of simple line chart programatically? I can't find a suitable method in the documentation.

I use [Ext.chart.interactions.CrossZoom](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.chart.interactions.CrossZoom.html) if its metter.

Comment: If this question seems incorrect to you for any reason, then please write why. I'm sure this task has a solution out of the box due to its triviality and I really can not find anything about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an undocumented `undoZoom` method in the CrossZoom [class](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/CrossZoom.js.html#Ext.chart.interactions.CrossZoom).
You can use it like so:

```
chart.getInteraction('crosszoom').undoZoom();
```

**Edit**

The cross zoom interaction keeps the history zoom in a `zoomHistory` property. The `undoZoom` method goes back, one step/zoom at a time, along the zoom history.

Based on `undoZoom` method, I've created an `resetZoom` method that directly resets the chart to its initial zoom:

```
Ext.define(null, {
    override: 'Ext.chart.interactions.CrossZoom',

    resetZoom: function () {
        var zoomMap = this.zoomHistory[0],
            axes = this.getChart().getAxes();

        if (zoomMap) {
            for (var i = 0; i < axes.length; i++) {
                var axis = axes[i];
                if (zoomMap[axis.getId()]) {
                    axis.setVisibleRange(zoomMap[axis.getId()]);
                }
            }
        }
        this.getUndoButton().setDisabled(true);
        this.zoomHistory = [];
        this.sync();
    }
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/264t

**Another Edit**

As [@SergeyNovikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2667065) has noted in the comments, and as you can see from the `undoZoom` method and `resetZoom` override, it all comes down to the axis' [setVisibleRange](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.chart.axis.Axis.html#placeholder-accessor-setVisibleRange) method. So you can also directly use it with min/max values as arguments to reset the zoom.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! Actually I can use `.setVisibleRange()` and min / max values for axis as arguments. You can add it to your answer to make it perfect.